# How to call a function and have it continue by pressing a key once?

Tags: java, processing

I want the `ball.move();` function in the code below to continue running after pressing space once. It only works if I continue pressing the space key.

```
void draw() {

if (start == true) {ball.move();}

}
```

```
void keyPressed() {

  if (key == ' '){start = true;}    

}

void keyReleased() {

  if (key == ' ') {start = false;}

}
```

It's for a Pong game I am making and each time the ball hits the edge it is teleported to the center of the canvas. That´s when I want to be able to start the ball movement manually again.

Here is the whole code:

```
Ball ball;
Player player1;
Player player2;

int scorePlayer1 = 0;
int scorePlayer2 = 0;

PFont font;

boolean start;

void setup() {

  size(1368,768);
  frameRate(144);
  noStroke();

  ball = new Ball(width/2, height/2, 30);
  player1 = new Player(15, height/2, 30, 150);
  player2 = new Player(width-15, height/2, 30, 150);

  ball.speedX = 10;

}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  textSize(40);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  font = loadFont("Arial-Black-48.vlw");
  textFont(font);

  ball.display();
  if (start == true) {ball.move();}
  player1.run();
  player2.run();

  //Score 
  if (ball.left() < 0) {
    scorePlayer2 = scorePlayer2 + 1;
    ball.x = width/2;
    ball.y = height/2;
  }

  if (ball.right() > width) {
    scorePlayer1 = scorePlayer1 +1;
    ball.x = width/2;
    ball.y = height/2;
  }

  text(scorePlayer1, width/2-75, 50);
  text(scorePlayer2, width/2+75, 50);

  //Collision
  if (ball.top() < 0) {
    ball.speedY = -ball.speedY;
  }

  if (ball.bottom() > height) {
    ball.speedY = -ball.speedY;
  }

  if (ball.left() < player1.right() && ball.y > player1.top()-10 && ball.y < player1.bottom()+10) {
    ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
    ball.speedY = map(ball.y - player1.y, -player1.h/2, player1.h/2, -5, 5);
  }

  if (ball.right() > player2.left() && ball.y > player2.top()-10 && ball.y < player2.bottom()+10) {
    ball.speedX = -ball.speedX;
    ball.speedY = map(ball.y - player2.y, -player2.h/2, player2.h/2, -5, 5);
  }

  if (player1.bottom() > height) {
    player1.y = height-player1.h/2;  
  }

  if (player1.top() < 0) {
    player1.y = player1.h/2;
  }

  if (player2.bottom() > height) {
    player2.y = height-player1.h/2;  
  }

  if (player2.top() < 0) {
    player2.y = player1.h/2;
  }

}

//Movement
void keyPressed() {

  player1.pressed((key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));
  player2.pressed((keyCode == UP), (keyCode == DOWN));   

  if (key == ' '){start = true;}    

}

void keyReleased() {

  player1.released((key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));
  player2.released((keyCode == UP), (keyCode == DOWN));

  if (key == ' ') {start = false;}

}

class Ball {

  float x;
  float y;
  float d;
  float speedX;
  float speedY;
  color c;

  //Constructor
  Ball(float tempX, float tempY, float tempD){

    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    d = tempD;
    speedX = 0;
    speedY = 0;
    c = (255);

  }

  void display() {

    fill(c);
    ellipse(x,y,d,d);

  }

  void move() {

    x = x + speedX;
    y = y + speedY;

  }

  //Collision help
  float top() {
    return y-d/2;
  }

  float bottom() {
    return y+d/2;
  }

  float left() {
    return x-d/2;
  }

  float right() {
    return x+d/2;
  }

}

class Player {

  float x, y;
  float w, h;
  float speedY = 0.0;
  color c;
  boolean moveUp = false, moveDown = false;

  //Constructor
  Player(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH){

    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    w = tempW;
    h = tempH;
    speedY = 0;
    c = (255);

  }

  void run() {

    display();
    move();

  }

  void display() {

    fill(c);
    rect(x-w/2, y-h/2, w, h);

  }

  //Movement
  void move() {

    if (!moveUp && !moveDown) {speedY = speedY * 0.85;}
    if (moveUp)               {speedY -= 1;} 
    if (moveDown)             {speedY += 1;}
    speedY = max(-7.0, min(7.0, speedY));
    y += speedY;


  }

  void pressed(boolean up, boolean down) {

    if (up) {moveUp = true;}
    if (down) {moveDown = true;}

  }

  void released(boolean up, boolean down) {

    if (up) {moveUp = false;}
    if (down) {moveDown = false;}

  }

  //Collision help
  float top() {
    return y-h/2;
  }

  float bottom() {
    return y+h/2;
  }

  float left() {
    return x-w/2;
  }

  float right() {
    return x+w/2;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, you are setting start to true when the key is pressed and false when the press is done. You can simply remove the line that sets start to false when the key press is done and the ball will always move when the space is pressed.

```
//Movement
void keyPressed() {

  player1.pressed((key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));
  player2.pressed((keyCode == UP), (keyCode == DOWN));   

  if (key == ' '){start = true;}    

}

void keyReleased() {

  player1.released((key == 'w' || key == 'W'), (key == 's' || key == 'S'));
  player2.released((keyCode == UP), (keyCode == DOWN));

  //if (key == ' ') {start = false;}

}
```

I suppose you want the ball to stop moving when space is pressed again. This can be done in your keyPressed method as well by toggling start instead of setting it to true. Something like `if (key == ' '){start = !start;}`

Comment: Now it starts and stops while toggling space!  Problem is I want the ball to stop in the center after each "point" and then move again after I press space.

Comment: you can add `start = false` in these situations. I suggest you rename the variable `start` to something more description like `ballMoving`

Comment: Where and how can I do that?

Comment: After this line (twice in your code) `ball.y = height/2;`, add `start = false;`. By the way this is not your code?

Comment: Okay, and yes it is (with help and inspiration). What about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you release the space bar, it sets the `start` field to `false`. Then when the next `draw()` method is called, it sees that `start==false` and so doesn't move the ball.

If you remove that line from the `keyReleased` method, then it should run correctly?